# How to merge with two queries in MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

Even though my previous post was partially correct, I created this post where I didn't get the exact result I wanted.

I cannot get properly answer mI want to find the wins, losses and draws of the team whose team_id is given according to the home and away results. The query I created always shows home team wins, losses and draws regardless of team_id. How can I correctly query the home and away wins, losses and draws of the team specified with the entered team_id?

My tables structures are;

teams table fields: team_id, team_name
leagues table fields: league_id, league_name
matches table fields: match_id, match_date, home_team_id, a.team_id, home_score, away_score, league_id

And also I cannot merge both queries. I think if both queries possible to merge it will give the result I expected.

Wrong working queries are :

```
-- Arsenal's Home W,L and D results query
    select t1.team_name hometeam, m.home_score,  t2.team_name awayteam, m.away_score,
             CASE WHEN m.home_score > m.away_score THEN 'W' 
                  WHEN m.home_score < m.away_score THEN 'L' 
                    WHEN m.home_score = m.away_score THEN 'D' 
             END AS results
    from   matches m
    join   teams  t1 on m.home_team_id = t1.team_id 
    join   teams  t2 on m.away_team_id = t2.team_id
    where  m.home_team_id = '21' or m.away_team_id = 21;
```

Results: (Away Wins shown as Lost and Away Lost shown as Win)

| HomeT | HS | AwayT | AS | results |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Brentford | 2 | Arsenal | 0 | W |
| Arsenal | 0 | Chelsea | 2 | L |
| Manchester City | 5 | Arsenal | 0 | W |
| Arsenal | 1 | Norwich City | 0 | W |
| Burnley | 0 | Arsenal | 1 | L |
| Arsenal | 3 | Tottenham Hotspur | 1 | W |
| Brighton & Hove Albion | 0 | Arsenal | 0 | D |
| Arsenal | 2 | Crystal Palace | 2 | D |

And

```
-- Arsenal's Away W,L and D results
select t1.team_name hometeam, m.home_score,  t2.team_name awayteam, m.away_score,
         CASE WHEN m.away_score > m.home_score THEN 'W' 
              WHEN m.away_score < m.home_score THEN 'L' 
                WHEN m.away_score = m.home_score THEN 'D' 
         END AS results
from   matches m
join   teams  t1 on m.home_team_id = t1.team_id 
join   teams  t2 on m.away_team_id = t2.team_id
where  m.home_team_id = '21' or m.away_team_id = 21;
```

Results: (Home Wins shown as Lost and Home Lost shown as Win )

| HomeT | HS | AwayT | AS | results |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Brentford | 2 | Arsenal | 0 | L |
| Arsenal | 0 | Chelsea | 2 | W |
| Manchester City | 5 | Arsenal | 0 | L |
| Arsenal | 1 | Norwich City | 0 | L |
| Burnley | 0 | Arsenal | 1 | W |
| Arsenal | 3 | Tottenham Hotspur | 1 | L |
| Brighton & Hove Albion | 0 | Arsenal | 0 | D |
| Arsenal | 2 | Crystal Palace | 2 | D |

Thanks in advance to those who will help.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```sql
select t1.team_name hometeam, m.home_score,  t2.team_name awayteam, m.away_score,
        CASE WHEN (m.home_team_id = 21 and m.home_score > m.away_score) or (m.away_team_id = 21 and m.home_score < m.away_score) THEN 'W' 
             WHEN (m.home_team_id = 21 and m.home_score < m.away_score) or (m.away_team_id = 21 and m.home_score > m.away_score) THEN 'L' 
             WHEN m.home_score = m.away_score THEN 'D' 
        END AS results
from matches m
join teams  t1 on m.home_team_id = t1.team_id 
join teams  t2 on m.away_team_id = t2.team_id
where m.home_team_id = 21 or m.away_team_id = 21;
```